# write access with MATLAB linux

Tags: matlab

```
f = fopen(fid1, 'r' );
g = fopen(folder_1\fid1.xml.TEMP', 'w' );
```

this works on windows and not on Linux.

is there a specific actions so that the lines above works on windows and on on Linux ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use other slash '/' and try.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that the file separator is platform-dependent. Try using the [filesep](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/filesep.html) global variable, and/or have a look at the [fullfile](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/fullfile.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = fopen(./fid1, 'r' );
g = fopen(./folder_1/fid1.xml.TEMP, 'w' );
```

For determining the OS type you can use:

```
if ispc
% use \
elseif isunix
% use /
else
% abort
end
```

Comment: i NEED TO SPECIFY THE NAME OF FOLDER , I try to do code to work on windows and on linux but not on linux only.(currently it works only on windows) and I try to look for a generic solution